# How do I write a struct with dynamic generics?

Tags: generics, rust, dynamic-dispatch

Let's say I have the following struct

```
trait T{}
struct A<X:T>{
    ...
}
```

I'm wondering whether something like this is possible

```
Box<A<dyn T>>
```

Currently I get errors

```
the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn T + 'static)`
```

but when I add

```
trait T:Sized{}
```

I get

```
the trait cannot be made into an object because it requires `Self: Sized`
```

Comment: Im pretty sure youd need a &dyn T

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, but generics have the `Sized` bound by default, which prevents them from being instantiated by a trait object, which is unsized. You need to specify `T: ?Sized`:

```rust
trait T {}
struct A<X: ?Sized + T> {}
```

E.g.:

```rust
trait T {}
impl T for () {}

struct A<X: ?Sized + T> {
    value: X,
}

fn foo() {
    let _ = Box::<A<()>>::new(A { value: () }) as Box<A<dyn T>>;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dec53a116f9afe668d0047428fbb1588).